# Analyse sensitivity of hyper-parameters of Machine Learning Models

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, experiment-design, hyperparameter, sensitivity-analysis

I want to analyse how sensitive my non neural net machine learning models are to the choice of the different parameters. I am currently using grid search to tune the models. Is there any method that I can use to get a good measure of the sensitivity of my models? Also, is there any quantitative method that gives me a measure of this?

Comment: Look into *design of experiments*, search this site. Maybe start with https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259139/machine-learning-for-optimization-of-configuration-file