# Choosing a space function for hyperopt

Tags: neural-networks, python, optimization, hyperparameter, bayesian-optimization

I was originally doing a grid search for my parameter optimization and with 7 parameters being optimized, it would take ages. So I am choosing to use hyperopt at this point.

I am however confused on what space function to choose for my learning rate and learning rate decay options. In my grid search, I was considering look at learning rate values of [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001] and learning rate decay values of [0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9997].

I was thinking about hp.uniform for the learning rate decay, but would there be a better option? I have no inclination into where the best model will be. Also for learning rate in this range what would be the best option? I am new to hyperopt but project lead wants me to utilize it.

Would hp.loguniform be appropriate for either of these?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There [was a similar question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/393973/analyse-sensitivity-of-hyper-parameters-of-machine-learning-models)  and also this: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/304/use-of-machine-learning-techniques-to-determine-parameter-values/330#330